# Update OnPropertyChanged on a Parent View from a child view

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding

In Xamarin for mac, I decided to make multiple views to be used within my main view using the MVVM pattern.

The thing is that I have a ListView within my MainPage which pulls a List of items from a model, and the list is populated within a child view, with its own ViewModel.

When I add a new service from the child view, I would like for the OnPropertyChanged event on the parent view model to trigger.

It is working by navigating to the parent view and setting the animation to false, but this is not really nice looking. It worked though when I had all code within one ViewModel.

How I tried to achieve this, and the errors I got:

0 - Accessing the  command within the child model from the parent model, and passing the propertychanged event handler along.

I Couldn't do it. I tried this by making a bindable command like below, but this is not doable for me as I don't think it is possible for the command to know when the property will be changed, which is the whole point of this problem. 
If it is doable, I don't know how.

```
        //public static readonly BindableProperty SaveServiceClickedCommandProperty =
    //    BindableProperty.Create(
    //        "SaveServiceClicked",
    //        typeof(Command),
    //        typeof(NewServiceViewModel),
    //        null);
```

1 - Passing the parent view model on the child view model, and put a OnPropertyChanged(nameof(parentModel.List)) at the clicked event handler.

```
public class ChildViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{





    public ICommand AddEntryClickedCommand { get; private set; }










    private MainModel mainModel;

    // property changed handler
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public NewServiceViewModel()
    {
        Navigation = MainPage;

        //async void execute() => await OpenPage();
        //OpenPageCommand = new Command(execute, () => !IsBusy);

        //async Task OpenPage()
        //{
        //    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        //}

        // Here I tried to access the data from within the main model.

        mainModel = new MainModel(Navigation);


        InitMainModel();

        void InitMainModel()
        {
            MainPage mainView = new MainPage();

            mainView.BindingContext = mainModel;


        }

        async void c1() => await AddEntryClicked();
        AddEntryClickedCommand = new Command(c1);



    }

    public async Task<bool> AddEntryClicked()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(mainModel.List))
    }
```

The attempt above created some errors as the object is already populated. 
Leading to me thinking that I don't have the right approach altogether.

My solution being to re-introduce the child view within the parent view, and change IsVisible according to the button being clicked or not, as I already did with other smaller component.
I have thought about pulling the list from the child view, but that's raises the same issue of non-null collection.

Of course, the code has been modified to show only the gist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two views(MainPage and childPage), there are have own viewmodels, but the properties are same? Could you post your layout xaml here? If you want model and view will update, when both of them changed, you can add the `Mode=TwoWay` in `Command`.

Comment: Hi. Already did this, and removed it to re add it. But Nothing.
I will remove this view and include it within the main page so that it work back again.
In my opinion, the whole issue is that underneath the hood, calling variables from another ViewModel instantiate another variable holding the same data, creating conflicts within the code. 
Anyhow, that's not a problem as the view is small, but would have been great to keep parent views and child view apart following the MVVM pattern, and to have the property handler being sharable everywhere.
I'm a C# noob, so certainly my fault...

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Leon.  In my opinion, not solvable.

I put the code back in the main ViewModel, and interacted with it from the main View, as I did prior to keep ContentView separated.
I still have view under the main page for the headers for example. 

I would have loved to learn a new trick to keep multiple ContentViews under a ContentPage and being able to share details between ViewModels easily though.

I assume I broke the MVVM convention. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Also, since I couldn't edit my answer above to give further details, the following video is, in my opinion, the best resource for multiple ContentView within ContentPages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dzv8CtUCchY

I personally liked the fact that he mentioned that variables needed to stay null at initialization. Thus kind of confirming that variables are initialized in both models underneath the view. 
Developers needs to watch out about this, because not knowing what you do can lead to a stack overflow.

Thanks again Leon, and cheers.